# Skipping deployment for some modules in an aggregate Maven POM

Tags: maven, tomcat, deployment

I have an aggregate Maven POM `foobar` that has several modules including `foobar-api` and `foobar-web`. The `foobar-web` POM actually creates a WAR file, and it uses the `tomcat7-maven-plugin` to deploy to Tomcat using the `tomcat7:deploy` goal.

If I bind the `tomcat7:deploy` goal to the `deploy` phase, I believe I could do a `mvn clean deploy` on the `foobar-web` project and have the WAR be automatically deployed to Tomcat. But if I were to do this on the `foobar` aggregate POM, wouldn't it complain with "Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element…"?

How could I turn off deployment for certain modules in an multi-module Maven project so that doing a `mvn deploy` on the aggregate POM would not fail on the non-web projects?

As an alternative, even if I don't bind the `tomcat7:deploy` goal to the `deploy` phase, how can I invoke the `tomcat7:deploy` goal on the aggregate POM and prevent an error for those modules that have no `tomcat7-maven-plugin` defined?

Answer (score 0):

You probably confused maven `deploy phase` and goal `deploy` of `tomcat7-maven-plugin`.

Maven `deploy` is phase of maven build lifecycle which is intended to copy result artifacts to remote repository.
More info: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

tomcat7:deploy by default is bind to package phase, so if you don't chnge this setting, you can only `deploy to tomacat` by runing `mvn clean package`.

If you want stay `tomcat7:deploy` binding to `deploy` maven phase you can add in your modules

```
<properties>
<maven.deploy.skip>true</maven.deploy.skip>
</properties>
```

but this brake at all maven deployment of those module.